# How to insertItem to 2nd colum in CListCtrl

Tags: c++, list, user-interface, mfc, edit

I am new to MFC & BGCControlBar.
Now I plan to use CBCGPListCtrl which is defined as:

```
class BCGCBPRODLLEXPORT CBCGPListCtrl : public CListCtrl
```

&

```
CBCGPListCtrl m_wndWatch;
```

Now in the demo code I plan to change:

```
int CWatchBar::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct) 
{
    if (CBCGPDockingControlBar::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    m_Font.CreateStockObject (DEFAULT_GUI_FONT);

    CRect rectDummy;
    rectDummy.SetRectEmpty ();

    // Create output pane:
        const DWORD dwStyle = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_VSCROLL | LVS_REPORT |  LVS_EDITLABELS ;

    m_wndWatch.Create (dwStyle, rectDummy, this, ID_LIST_1);
    m_wndWatch.SendMessage (LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE, 0,
                        LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT | LVS_EX_GRIDLINES);
    m_wndWatch.InsertColumn (0, _T("Variable"), LVCFMT_LEFT, 100);
    m_wndWatch.InsertColumn (1, _T("Value"), LVCFMT_LEFT, 100);

    m_wndWatch.InsertItem (0, _T("m_nCount"));
    m_wndWatch.SetItemText (0, 1, _T("100"));

    m_wndWatch.SetFont (&m_Font);

    return 0;
}
```

What I get is a list(as in pic), I can only edit the 1st colum and the data can not be retained. **How can I edit the second column text and make the data retainable?**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a grid control rather than a CListCtrl (or derived class). Actually, it's possible to add support for edition in other columns but it's a looooooot of work and not the kind of thing I'd recommend to a newcomer.

According to [this page of their web site](http://www.bcgsoft.com/featuretour/tour194.htm), they have a grid control.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you need to do in order to make a MFC CListCtrl editable.  This is a very broad overview without going into too many details:

1. As mentioned above it is quite a bit of work and you need to derive a class from CListCtrl, since CListCtrl by itself does not allow you to explicitly edit all of the columns.
2. You need a routine that will calculate the row/column number of the particular cell you clicked on, given a cursor position `CPoint`.
3. In the derived `CListCtrl` class you also need a method to edit the selected cell, creating and making visible a `CEdit` control of the appropriate size.
4. Create a derived `CEdit` control, such that it sends the `LVN_ENDLABELEDIT` message and self-destructs upon completion.

An example Visual Studio 2010 project implementing an editable list control is downloadable from this site:

http://www.technical-recipes.com/2014/making-a-mfc-list-control-editable/

Upon running/debugging the example, you get an example dialog project implementing an editable list control as shown:

[image]